# How can i write and fix my regex? ( ABCD / ABCD.view / ABCD_1 / ABCD_a)

Tags: regex

I’m trying to write regex

- `https://.*ABCD`
- `https://.*ABCD.view`
- `https://.*ABCD_1`
- `https://.*ABCD_r`

If there are these 4 urls, i’d like to export only these `https://.*ABCD, https://.*ABCD.view` 2 urls, not these urls `https://.*ABCD_1, https://.*ABCD_r`

I was trying to make it like this

```
https://.*ABCD.*
```

But this one includes these urls `https://.*ABCD_1, https://.*ABCD_r`

I googled it but no luck.

How can i fix and write regex?

Comment: Match the end of the string using $ and don’t allow _, e.g. `https://.*ABCD(\.view)?$`

Comment: You might want to start from this to match a URL and adapt it to exclude _: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809401/what-is-a-good-regular-expression-to-match-a-url#3809435

Answer (score 0):

This regex excludes underscore and space for valid URL:

```
^https://[^_\s]+$
```

Try this tool for different regex:

https://regex101.com/